# read data from xlsx file using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader, phpexcel-1.8.0

[image]

This is My test.xlsx sheet, I want to take only B table data from this Xlsx Sheet Using PHPExcel. (Or any other way).

Please Give Some Suggestion about My Problem.

Thank You

Comment: Why not just have it on a separate sheet itself?

Comment: No...This is my input, I want to take particularly that B table for my calculation..

Answer (score 1):

Pass the cells to be reading

```
require 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

$excelFile = 'files/excel1.xlsx';
if (file_exists($excelFile))
{
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($excelFile);
    $excelData = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->rangeToArray('H8:K16');

}
```